# Performance improvement suggestion for query

Tags: sql-server, sqlperformance

Below is my query and execution plan. i am looking to improve performance Last day i created one question and it was not clear. So i am adding it here with proper query and execution plan

```
 INSERT INTO #FinalResultTable              
   (              
      [Disclosure Category]              
     , [Line #]              
     , [AllocationProcessId]        
     , [Line Description (Long)]              
     , [Line Description (Short)]              
     , [Segment Start Date]                   
     , [Segment End Date]              
     , [Tag Group1]              
     , [Tag Group2]              
     , [Tag Group3]              
     , [Tag Group4]          
     , [UniqueTransactionId]            
      , [TransactionName] 
        , InvestmentNumber               
    )     
 SELECT              
         WSS.Name ,              
         SS.SortSequence AS [LineNo],        
         AD.AllocationProcessId,              
         SS.UnformattedQuestionText AS [LineDescriptionLong],              
         SS.ShortDescription AS [LineDescriptionShort],              
         [SegmentStartDate],              
         [SegmentEndDate],              
         [TagDescription1],              
         [TagDescription2],              
         [TagDescription3],              
         [TagDescription4],              
         [UniqueTransactionId],                
         [TransactionName],              

         InvestmentNumber             
        FROM [#AllocationData] AD              
        JOIN [#SupplementalSection]  SS ON
         (SS.Code = AD.Code AND AD.SupplementalSectionQnId IS NULL)     or
         AD.SupplementalSectionQnId = SS.SupplementalSectionQnId 


        JOIN Workpaper.SupplementalSection WSS WITH(NOLOCK)               
        ON SS.SupplementalSectionId = WSS.Id  
        WHERE WSS.IsActive = 1 AND WSS.IsDeleted = 0 AND WSS.formTypeId = @formTypeId
```

as per the execution plan table insert cost 75%.total cost of this is 29%. For AllocationData i have nonclustered index for SupplementalSectionQnId,Code

Comment: To make a "proper" execution plan available to others, use https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan .

Comment: Did you upload your execution plan I dont see it?  You mention INSERT is 75%, I dont see an insert in your query?

Comment: i coulnt upload execution plan since its size is greater than 2mb. this is a small part of my query.

Comment: Try simplifying the query until you have the smallest possible one that still exhibits a perf problem (and/or work the other way around from an empty query that you gradually build up). If the execution plan is *that* big, it probably includes a bunch of operations on columns that aren't actually the problem. Divide and conquer. You can also use `SET STATISTICS IO ON` to get an idea of the big consumers in the query (particular tables with a large number of reads/writes that may be lacking indexes).

Comment: please the execution plan https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJAep5EHN

Comment: what is hash match cost ?

Comment: I don't see any major problems with the query, other than you're handling millions of rows. Do you need all that information? Have you tried having one insert for rows with SupplementalSectionQnId and one with that column on NULL? That could be helpful.

Comment: you mean using union right? i tried it .actually then the query was taking more time